# Specified offlineSchema does not match database Offline schema previously used for cache path

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-sync-framework

I have implemented WinRt sync framework from Fabrikam sample(https://syncwinrt.codeplex.com/). The frame work creates local db and works fine when I run the app and sync for the first time. when I rerun the app it throws an error.

Exception Details:

System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Specified offlineSchema does not match database Offline schema previously used for cache path
  Source=Microsoft.Synchronization.ClientServices.Win8
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Synchronization.ClientServices.SQLite.SQLiteContext.CheckSchemaAndUri(OfflineSchema offlineSchema, Uri uri, String scope)
       at Microsoft.Synchronization.ClientServices.SQLite.SQLiteContext.LoadSchema()
       at Microsoft.Synchronization.ClientServices.SQLite.SQLiteContext.d__0.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at mySync.ContextModel.ContextModel.<Sync>d__0.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at my_Windows_App.App.d__4.MoveNext()
  InnerException:

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my db had tables with name starting in caps. renaming them in lower case did the trick for me.